# how many java virtual machine extst on computer

Tags: java, jvm

I don't understand how many jvm exist on my computer. One or more?

For example.
I open eclipse, jboss and another java program. How many jvm exist in my computer? 3 or 1?

Answer (score 3):

Typically a new VM is started every time you execute a java program.  The JVM is nothing more than the environment that the Java program is running in .  However, some programs create multiple JVMs so that they can run a number of Java programs independently.  Applications servers give you the option to control the number of JVMs they start, and what to use them for.  For the example you cited you probably have 3 JVMs, but depending upon how JBoss is configured, and what you have installed there, you might have more.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the command `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jps -l`, it will list how many JVM instances on you System and show the man class.